# How to integrate Twilio's Voice API service with AWS S3 Storage?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, twilio

I'm trying to create a short program that calls a user's number and records the conversation using Twilio and send the recording to an S3 bucket

Here's a link that does it to a dropbox instead of an S3:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/recording-saving-outbound-voice-calls-python-twilio-dropbox

Here's the code I have so far that allows me to call and recorded conversations go to Twilio's online storage:

```
    call = client.calls.create(
                            record=True,
                            url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                            to='+15558889988',
                            from_='+18889992222'
                        )

    print(call.sid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twillio has inbuilt mechanism to do it, any specific use case you want to do it. https://www.twilio.com/blog/announcing-external-aws-s3-storage-support-for-voice-recordings

Comment: Thanks for this! It doesn't say where that JSON snippet file goes or if I need to make additional changes to my code because I'm storing to S3

Answer (score 1):

When you create the call you can also create a webhook that tells you when the recording is ready. When you then receive the webhook you can get the file and send it to S3.

```
...
    record=True,
    recording_status_callback=callbackURL+"/recordings",
    recording_status_callback_event=["completed"],
...
```

Comment: I've setup my Twilio account to link to the S3 Bucket URL with my secret key info however I'm not sure how my code will change. What is the callback URL you are referring to?

Comment: If you're using the link provided by Vikram, then you don't need to change anything about your code. You should be all set. Create a new call with record=True and check your S3 bucket.